# React Native background geolocation not work

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I tried to find free solution for background location for Android RN app and used [this](https://github.com/michalchudziak/react-native-geolocation) lib.

But it seems it not support background geolocation. I used this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
Geolocation.setRNConfiguration({
skipPermissionRequests: false,
locationProvider: 'android',
})

Geolocation.watchPosition(
({ coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lon }}) => {
// my code here...
},
(error) => console.error(error),
{ interval: 1000, enableHighAccuracy: true, distanceFilter: 1 },
)
}, [])
```

It works fine but only app is in focus.
Backgrounded app do not watch for position.

I saw this module https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation but it's paid.

Do I have any free possibilities to get background location?

I tried several alternative libs, but they are outdated or not work in background.

---

My RN version is 0.71.6

### UPDATE: Solution found!

Helped this Expo lib: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location.
For bare React Native use this instructions to install expo module https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules

Working and tested code looks like this (here we watch for changing geolocation and get coordinates):

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import type { FC } from 'react'
import * as Location from 'expo-location'
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager'


const App: FC = () => {
  // ... prev code

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()

      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.error('Permission to access location was denied')
        return
      }

      TaskManager.defineTask('WATCH_BG_GEO', ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
        if (error) return

        // 
        // Your logic on change geolocation will be here
        // 

        // Example - get lon and lat
        const newCoords = {
          lat: locations[0].coords.latitude,
          lon: locations[0].coords.longitude,
        }

        // Still works in background mode!!
      })

      // Handler for changing geolocation
      Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('WATCH_BG_GEO', {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
        timeInterval: 1000,
        activityType: Location.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
        distanceInterval: 1,
        foregroundService: {
          notificationTitle: 'GPS',
          notificationBody: ' enabled',
        }
      })
    })()
  }, [])


  return (
    // ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-foreground-service` beside `react-native-geolocation-service`. Here is an example:

https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/example/src/App.tsx

It's completely free.

Comment: Thanks but it is not work for geolocation case. At least I can't use it this way.